# Creating directories on certain Android versions

Tags: android, android-permissions

I tested this code with Genymotion Marshmallow and with Nougat on my HTC 10, and it worked on both.
Now I tried Android 7.0 on Genymotion and it didn't create the directories.

Any idea why?

```
File file = new File(Environment
    .getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator +
    "SchoolAssist" + File.separator + lesson_name);

boolean isDir = file.exists();
if (!isDir)
    isDir = file.mkdirs();

if (isDir) {
    Intent notes = new Intent(getActivity(), NotesManager.class);
    notes.putExtra("dir", file.getAbsolutePath());
    startActivity(notes);
}
else
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error creating directory", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Edit: My manifest contains these lines:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: is it possible that you just forgot to grant the permission on the last device?

Comment: I wasn't required to grand permission on any of the devices

Comment: You need to check for permissions in the code yourself on `API >= 23` - https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 0):

In your code the Toast will be shown even when creating the directory worked. The Activity will only be started when the file already existed before calling your code.

Try this:

```
File file = new File(Environment
            .getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator +
            "SchoolAssist" + File.separator + lesson_name);

if(!file.exists()) {
    if(file.mkdirs()) {
        startNotesManager();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error creating directory", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
} else {
    startNotesManager();
}
```

And implement this helper method for starting the Activity:

```
private void startNotesManager() {
    Intent notes = new Intent(getActivity(), NotesManager.class);
    notes.putExtra("dir", file.getAbsolutePath());
    startActivity(notes);
}
```